# Winforms Build Date Not Showing in Installed App

Tags: winforms, setup-deployment

OK try to follow this:  I am using a Pre-Build event command line like so...

```
echo %date% %time:~0,5% > "$(ProjectDir)\Resources\BuildDate.txt"
```

This gives me a resource named BuildDate that I can read and get the build time like so...

```
String date = Properties.Resources.BuildDate;
this.Text = string.Format("My Project: build {0}", date);
```

My app then has a title bar with an included build date.  This works in debug mode from the F5 and ctrl+F5 builds, giving me the datetime of the build.

BUT:
When I rebuild the project setup msi using a **deployment project**, the whole project builds normally, but the date is from months ago.  It's like the installer is seeing that the resource file is there and refusing to update it.

Here are the resource settings for BuildDate.

[Resource Object Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jppg8.png)

Comment: There is a better way to do that: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+assembly+version+date

Comment: Yep. first thing that comes up is what I was working from.  Anything more specific?

Comment: Except that it's NOT a setting, it's a "resource".  There is no "scope" for resources.